# How to find MAC address on RHEL 7.3?

Tags: rhel, mac-address

How do I find my `MAC address` on `RHEL 7.3`? When I ran `ifconfig -a | grep HWaddr`, nothing showed. It's an `EC2` instance, if that means any deviation from the norm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command `ip link` shows the MAC address on all interfaces.

Comment: is it the `link/ether` field under `eth0`?

Comment: Yes, that is the MAC address. If it is not applicable, like for the loopback interface, `00:00:00:00:00:00` is shown instead.